# Selector function with int parameter?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Using Cocos2d-iphone, and objective-c game development framework.

I create a button with:

```
CCMenuItemImage *slot = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"BattleMoveSelectionSlot1.png" 
                                                       selectedImage:@"BattleMoveSelectionSlot2.png"
                                                              target:self selector:@selector(moveChosen:i)];
```

And my `moveChosen` method is:

```
-(void)moveChosen:(int)index {

}
```

However, for some reason I get an error on `@selector(moveChosen:i)` where i is an integer. How, then, may I pass an integer parameter to my function when the button is pressed?

The error is

> Expected ':'

Comment: See this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899223/how-can-i-pass-an-int-value-through-a-selector-method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899223/how-can-i-pass-an-int-value-through-a-selector-method
**see this thread**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't include any argument names in the selector:

```
@selector(moveChosen:)
```

Selectors don't allow for binding parameters.

Comment: So I definitely can't pass on arguments?

Comment: @Omega: No, you can't bind arguments using selectors. Usually the parameters for actions get should let you identify the situation, see Jonathans answer.

Answer (score 4):

Georg is correct. Note that as implemented, this will invoke undefined behaviour since `index` is an `int` but the action method it's being used as expects an object (`id`) there, not an `int`. The signature of an action method is:

```
- (void)methodName:(id)sender;
```

Or, when used with Interface Builder:

```
- (IBAction)methodName:(id)sender;
```

(`IBAction` is an alias of `void`. The two are semantically different but functionally identical.)

Where `sender` is the object that sent the action message--in this case, the object you created and assigned to the `slot` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Georg is partially correct. For your example, it would be:

```
@selector(moveChosen:)
```

But note: if you have more than one parameter, you do include the formal parameter names to get the selector. If your function signature were:

```
- (void)moveChosen:(int)index withThing:(Thing*)thing
```

then the selector would be:

```
@selector(moveChosen:withThing:)
```

Comment: I meant the actual parameter naems. What you show is the interleaved method name: ["For methods with multiple parameters, Objective-C's method names are interleaved with the parameters"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6).

Answer (score 1):

The selector is just the name of the message that you want to send. The arguments will be provided when it is called — which means CCMenuItemImage will decide what argument is passed. If CCMenuItemImage does not support providing an integer parameter, you can't make it do that.