# how can i pass an int value through a selector method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, type-conversion, selector

I want to pass an `int` value from my selector method, but the selector method takes only an object type parameter.

```
int y =0;
[self performselector:@selector(tabledata:) withObject:y afterDelay:0.1];
```

Method execution is here

```
-(int)tabledata:(int)cellnumber {
   NSLog(@"cellnumber: %@",cellnumber);
   idLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order Id: %@",[[records objectAtIndex:cellnumber] objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

but I am not getting exact integer value in my method, I am only getting the id value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The easiest solution, if you 'own' the target selector, is to wrap the int argument in an NSNumber:

```
-(int)tabledata:(NSNumber *)_cellnumber {
    int cellnumber = [_cellnumber intValue];
    ....
}
```

To call this method you would use:

```
[self performselector:@selector(tabledata:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:y] afterDelay:0.1];
```

Comment: cellnumber printing null value in nslog.

Comment: cellnumber is not a pointer, so how can it be NULL? Are you referring to _cellnumber? Also, use "%d" to log integer values, and "%@" to log NSNumber values.

Answer (score 15):

This works also for an `int` parameter, which is especially useful, if you are unable to change the signature of the selector you want to perform.

```
SEL sel = @selector(tabledata:);

NSMethodSignature *signature = [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:sel];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
invocation.selector = sel;
// note that the first argument has index 2!
[invocation setArgument:&y atIndex:2];

// with delay
[invocation performSelector:@selector(invokeWithTarget:) withObject:self afterDelay:0.1];
```

Comment: Why should we prefer complete breakdown to low-level (NSMethodSignature) over simple casting or making an object? The whole mess for what?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:, use an NSTimer, thusly:

```
int y = 0;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 repeats:NO block:^(NSTimer *timer) {
    [self tabledata:y];
}];
```

You can pass whatever you want in the timer block.

Comment: `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:repeats:block:` is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer