# Objective C performselector with integer object arguments gives garbage value

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector

I have a **Rectangle** object with the following interface:

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject

  @property int height, width;
  -(void) setWidth:(int)w andHeight: (int)h;

@end
```

I have an implementaion of it and an object (say `r`) made from it. When I call

```
[r setWidth: 5 andHeight: 6];
```

I get the correct results when I verify it through `[r height]`. However, when I am using `performselector` to do the same:

```
NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:45];
[r performSelector:@selector(setWidth:andHeight:) withObject:myNumber
            withObject:myNumber];
```

calling `[r height]` prints some garbage value (looks like some address) wen the expected value is 45. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `NSNumber` isn't the same as `int`. Your method doesn't take `NSNumber` objects as parameters. BTW - why are you using `performSelector` instead of calling the method directly?

Comment: it is just not supported.

Comment: @maddy, no particular reason, just experimenting.

Comment: @BryanChen, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899223/how-can-i-pass-an-int-value-through-a-selector-method ?

Comment: @Cupidvogel Notice in that other answer the solution was to change the method parameters to be `NSNumber` instead of `int`.

Comment: @rmaddy, ahh, right, forgot to notice. You can add this as answer, I will up vote and mark it.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue and solved it using `NSInvocation`.
The code something like the following should work, although it became wordy:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"setWidth:andHeight:");
NSMethodSignature *signature = [r methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
[invocation setSelector:selector];
int x = 5;
int y = 6;
[invocation setArgument:&x atIndex:2]; // 0 and 1 are reserved
[invocation setArgument:&y atIndex:3];
[invocation invokeWithTarget:r];
```

Answer (score 3):

performSelector can only be used to call methods where all arguments have object type. If your method has integer parameters, you can't use performSelector.

Comment: ...and if you truly need to indirectly call a method with non-object parameters, use `NSInvocation`.

Comment: Yes @gnasher729, I learnt that. However you can mention that I can change the function signature to accept NSNumbers instead, and inside them derive the actual integer value out of them. That will work.

Answer (score 2):

As gnasher says, you can't do that. You can use NSInvocation, or use GCD and blocks.